# No step-definition method match found for: karate.forEach(list, fun)

Tags: karate

I am getting an error while executing below code.
no step-definition method match found for: karate.forEach(list, fun)

```
Scenario: karate forEach operation on lists
    * def res = []
    * def fun = function(x){ karate.appendTo(res, x * x) }
    * def list = [1, 2, 3]
    * karate.forEach(list, fun)
    * match res == [1, 4, 9]
```

Karate version - 0.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `* eval karate.forEach(list, fun)` or upgrade.

Comment: @karate_begineer for those who can read - there is such a thing as release notes: https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases